# Set position of TextView in RemoteView during runtime

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Dear all, I am trying to set the position of a TextView within an appwidget.

Basically, the direct access to properties af the TextView works:

```
myRemoteView.setTextColor(R.id.myTextView, Color.WHITE);   //works
```

Also indirectly, I can access the TextView properties:

```
myRemoteView.setInt(R.id.myTextView, "setTextColor", Color.BLUE); // works
```

And setting float values also works:

```
myRemoteView.setFloat(R.id.myTextView, "setTextSize", 25); // works
```

Now I'm trying to shift the x position of the TextView by 5 pixels:

```
myRemoteView.setFloat(R.id.myTextView, "setTranslationX", 5); // does not work
myRemoteView.setFloat(R.id.myTextView, "setX", 5); // does not work
myRemoteView.setInt(R.id.myTextView, "setLeft", 5); // does not work
```

I tried FrameLayout and RelativeLayout, and also AbsoluteLayout (depreciated). Nothing works. But there must be a way to do that. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

###### At the time of the answer, the RemoteViews API does not allow you to set translation or position

However, you can achieve the desired effect by setting the padding for the parent of your TextView
[RemoteViews#setViewPadding(int, int, int, int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setViewPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Or, since API 31, you can also set the margin for your TextView
[RemoteViews#setViewLayoutMargin(int, int, float, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setViewLayoutMargin(int,%20int,%20float,%20int))

Answer (score -4):

```
LayoutParams lp = myRemoteView.getLayoutParams();
lp.marginLeft = 5; 
myRemoteView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: setLayoutParams does not exist for RemoteViews

Comment: This would work except RemoteViews doesn't support such things even in Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.