# Set position of view in RemoteView during runtime

Tags: java, android, remoteview

I'm looking for a way to change the position of a view in a
 homescreen widget/remoteview during runtime.
I also saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153484/set-position-of-textview-in-remoteview-during-runtime) before but the answer given there didn't help me or even work.

For example:

I'm trying to shift the x position of the TextView by 5 pixels:

```
myRemoteView.setFloat(R.id.myTextView, "setTranslationX", 5); // does not work
myRemoteView.setFloat(R.id.myTextView, "setX", 5); // does not work
myRemoteView.setInt(R.id.myTextView, "setLeft", 5); // does not work
```

I couldn't find somewhere else a useful answer that could help me.

Comment: Did you solve this man?

Answer (score 0):

You could try inflating a different layout with your `RemoteViews`, one with the widgets in your desired position. I am not sure that it will work, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since API 31, setTranslationX can be called on RemoteViews, since it is has been annotated as RemotableViewMethod. Either with:

```
myRemoteView.setFloat(R.id.myTextView, "setTranslationX", 5f)
```

or by using an extension method from RemoteViewsCompat:

```
myRemoteView.setViewTranslationXDimen(R.id.myTextView, 5f, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX)
```